# How should I pass variables between independent parallel tcl procs/scripts

Tags: tcl, obsolete

I have an obsolete, mission critical application that runs gui displays with tcl behind some items (some aren't as complex)

I am trying to get some gui elements to pass flags around to switch certain displays off, or switch modes.

Globals, and upvar 0 don't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you'll need to provide some sample code to let people understand better what you are trying to achieve. Are you using Tk?

Comment: Technically it might be tk, but the problem is that I have "logical functions" tied to different buttons. I have signals coming from different places and I simply want to switch from  normal signals to backups if the user hits the backup button (or any sensible analogue).

Comment: Sample code isn't likely to be helpful. I have two (or more) simple scripts that run with unknown scheduling that simply need to share some flags.

Comment: Since they are completely separate processes, using custom signals seems like the simplest thing: [TclX](https://github.com/flightaware/tclx) has [kill and signal commands](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tclx8.2/TclX.n.html#lbAF)

Comment: That you mention global and upvar makes me think your "independent" procs are in the same process (otherwise Donal's answer about IPC in general applies).  If they are in the same process then other options might be possible, but we need much more detail on your actual situation to provide helpful answers (processes, hosts, threads, interps context)

Comment: If it is just sharing some flags, even just using environment variables might be enough (they're shared by the whole process). You can't synchronise between threads with them in a good way, and they're copied on subprocess launch, but they are fine for basic flags. For more complexity, a config file or SQLite DB are easy.

Answer (score 1):

If they're in separate processes, you're talking doing Interprocess Communication (IPC). That's a *big* topic!

If you aren't needing to communicate that much with high degrees of synchrony, an easy way is to use an SQLite database. All processes can open it and do transactions in it to store and retrieve data and so on. Very convenient... especially as you can also use third-party tools to have a look at that shared state.

If they're all using Tk then *maybe* you can use `send`? It's easy, but only turns itself on when security settings are just right. I've done nothing with that mechanism for years...

Otherwise, a local socket (on `localhost`) ia fast on most platforms, or you can use pipes (including named pipes). That gets you a communication channel (bidirectional in the case of a socket) that you can use. The `comm` package in Tcllib builds on top of that.

To synchronise a variable, use a write trace to work out when to update the other side.

Comment: No code: too big a topic, too many nuances.